# Algorithm counter is broken with journal style file

Tags: numbering, templates, algorithms

With the style file gSCS2e.cls, found at http://www.tandf.co.uk/journals/authors/gscslatex.zip as well as the algorithm package, if I compile the following LaTeX document, the Algorithm counter seems to be broken. It is stuck at 1 and does not increment. Specifically, the final words in my example document are "This is Algorithm 1" repeated twice. The Algorithm counter increments within a section, however. I get the expected results with other style files, so there is probably something wrong with the style file. I was not successful in obtaining a solution from the journal. I am sure this is well beyond my knowledge, hence I'm asking for help here.

The journal proofs do not show this problem. I initially thought they had fixed the problem in a more recent version of the class file, but after repeated requests and much confusion, I think it is possible that someone hand-edited the output. At any rate, I have never seen a version of this class file more recent than the version I have been using all along, namely, 2.4 ("First released 2008/05/02"). Unfortunately this is a real problem for me because I cannot circulate preprints with this brokenness.

```
\documentclass{gSCS2e}
\usepackage{algorithm, algpseudocode}
\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\maketitle

\section{First section}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{First algorithm}
\label{first}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State some stuff
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\section{Second section}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Second algorithm}
\label{second}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State some more stuff
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

This is Algorithm~\ref{first}. This is Algorithm~\ref{second}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Including section numbers in counters is a better solution for journal papers (at least in IEEE journals). There is a package option for it: `\usepackage[section]{algorithm}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The algorithm counter is reset at each section. That's because the `gSCS2e` class defines an algorithm environment. This uses a counter with the same name `algorithm` which is bound to the `section` counter. From `gSCS2e.cls`:

```
\newtheorem{algorithm}{\global\algorithmtrue{\bf\algorithmname}}[section]
```

You could remove that dependency, for example using the [`chngcntr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/chngcntr) package. This package provides commands for setting and removing relationships of counters, i.e. it allows to customize if a counter is reset when another counter is incremented, or not.

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{algorithm}{section}
```

Comment: @Stefan: Can you give more details, please? For example, why is there no problem with other class files? What is resetting the counter? If this is the style file, it seems unlikely it would have special code for the algorithm package.

Comment: @Faheem: I added an explanation.

Comment: I was just writing the same answer.  Alternatively, if you want the algorithms numbered within a section, you can use `\counterwithin{algorithm}{section}` This will give Sec.Alg numbering.

Comment: @Alan: That would look like Algorithm 1.1, Algorithm 1.2 etc?

Comment: @Stefan: I see. LaTeX has no namespaces, so one algorithm counter interferes with the other?

Comment: @Faheem, yes, that's what I meant by Sec.Alg numbering.  As for the namespace issue, in principle there is, but there are ways around it depending on how things are defined.

Comment: @Stefan: Can you elaborate on what the chngcntr package does? Thanks.

Comment: @Faheem: such class definitions are global, and so are those of of packages. That's why we can get conflicts. Here it was just hidden.

Comment: @Stefan: Not sure what you mean by the comment above, sorry. Want to take it to chat?

Comment: @Faheem: I added explanation regarding the `chngcntr` package. Well, conflict here just means having two "things" with the same name. Usually it causes an error, this time it didn't, that's why it's hard to notice.

Comment: If the class file writers had anticipated that someone might use an algorithm counter for a different purpose, could they have done some defensive programming?
And by that I don't calling the counter something else, since any name could be used by someone else. I mean putting it in a private namespace or similar.

Comment: @Stefan: Ah, I think I see what you mean. Usually LaTeX would produce an error if such a thing happened. This time it didn't.